# Installing python 3.12.1 using pyenv encounters error

Tags: python, pyenv, lzma

OS: Mac M3
Error:
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/Users/phoenix/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/lzma.py", line 27, in 
from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
WARNING: The Python lzma extension was not compiled. Missing the lzma lib?

I have already tried to install backports.lzma but still not working.
I also tried installing lower version but it is still the same.
I'm not using homebrew to install modules.
Any help will be appreciated.